# How to print more than one line with tcpdf and php

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to print out a dynamic report to pdf. I need to write multiple lines to a page, though everything I find seems to limit to just one single text line.
How do you write multiple lines to multiple locations/x,y on a document?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieId4.png
My issue is identical to this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389550/tcpdf-multiple-writecell-on-a-line  but it was never answered.

line 65 fails to appear/display.

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

$printdata = $_SESSION['printdata'];
$pieces = explode(":", $printdata);

require_once('/var/www/localhost/htdocs/contactdb/tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('/var/www/localhost/htdocs/contactdb/tcpdf/examples/lang/eng.php');
require_once('/var/www/localhost/htdocs/contactdb/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


// set margins
//$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
//$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
//$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
//$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set JPEG quality
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);


// Image example with resizing
$pdf->Image('edit1forbrad_program.jpg', 10, 10, 480, 680, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

$txt1 = "Some sample text".$pieces[0];
$txt2 = $pieces[1];
$txt3 = "".$pieces[2];
$txt4 = "".$pieces[3];
$txt5 = "".$pieces[4];
$txt6 = "".$pieces[5];
$txt7 = "".$pieces[6];
$txt8 = "".$pieces[7];
$txt9 = "".$pieces[8];
$txt10 = "".$pieces[9];
$txt11 = "".$pieces[10];
$txt12 = "".$pieces[11];
$txt13 = "".$pieces[12];
$txt14 = "".$pieces[13];
$txt15 = "".$pieces[14];
$txt16 = "".$pieces[15];
$txt17 = "".$pieces[16];


$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 16);
$pdf->SetX(30);
$pdf->Write(150, $txt2, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->MultiCell(180, $txt2, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_009.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: why dont you concatenate to a single string?

Comment: @Dagon each phase / variable / $pieces[''] value will have a different x,y coordinates. So they really need there own function.

Comment: You are missing your height param -> [`MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, ...)`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece) -> `$pdf->MultiCell(180, XXX (Missing), $txt2, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);`

Comment: @Sean first output line is perfectly located. Second or more never appears.

Comment: I have tried 2 MultiCell and 2 Cells and mix matched and everything. The second output command fails to render.

Comment: you only write the $txt2, nothing else

Comment: Without setting your height, my assumption is that `$pdf->Y` is not increasing properly, so it could be overlapping the first, so they are stacked, not below.

Comment: @Sean unfortunately it's not an over lap issue. the 150 to 180 would put them far away from each other. I have tried many settings and combos.

Comment: @Sean there were over lapping. I have 2 multicells showing now. All crazy, but they are there. Thank you!